# Adjust magnetic auto-lock sensitivity

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, samsung-nexus-10, smart-cover

I just bought a case for my Nexus 10 tablet ([EasyAcc Smart Cover](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00AH3BW8E/ref=oh_details_o00_s00_i00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)), but it seems the magnetic auto-lock sometimes thinks the cover is closed when the cover is flipped to the back side, behind the device. This especially happens when holding the tablet open in my hand, and it's easy to accidentally adjust the position of the cover on the back.

Since this false positive condition doesn't always happen, I'm guessing a simple sensitivity change might be enough to make the auto-lock feature of the cover work proprely. Another possible fix could be to have some sort of delay, os that when the system detects the lid as "closed", it'd wait for a few secs to see if it stays in closed state, and only then put the device to sleep.

**Is there a way to adjust the magnetic auto-lock sensitivity?**

*(Nexus 10 tablet, running Android 4.2.2)*

Comment: Sounds like the simplest solution would probably be to stick a small piece of something non-magnetic (strip of plastic?) on the case in front of the magnet to just lift it slightly further away from the device when you flip the cover over?

Answer (score 1):

It's very unlikely that you can control the sensitivity. Most of these magnetic switches are simple reed switches: the magnet pulls two contacts together, closing the switch. The software simply gets an on/off signal, not a quantity it can filter.

It might be possible to add the delay solution you suggest in a [custom-rom](/questions/tagged/custom-rom), but I don't know of any with this functionality.